# Marshalling / unmarshalling POJO with Jackson2 for RabbitMQ. Without type set in the headed?

Tags: jackson, marshalling, spring-amqp

I'm trying to get java object from Rabbit but got this

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve __TypeId__ in header
```

So I can change remote server format how I should update my bean then?

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

and how I can send back message?

with DefaultClassMapper

Rise the same error

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve __TypeId__ in header
```

Code

```
@Bean
public DefaultClassMapper typeMapper() {
    DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    typeMapper.setDefaultType(MyType.class);
    return typeMapper;
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(DefaultClassMapper defaultClassMapper) {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    jsonMessageConverter.setClassMapper(defaultClassMapper);
    return jsonMessageConverter;
}
```

I cant convert Object to JSON. 
 I have convertor class

```
   public class MySendTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MySendType> { 
   @Override
   public void serialize(MySendType mySendType, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {   //.. impl }}
```

And class itself

```
  @JsonSerialize(using = MySendTypeSerializer.class)
  public class MySendType { 
       // Regular POJO
  }
```

All this stuff never called despite the fact that Deserializer with @JsonDeserialize  works well.  Probably I've missed something in configuration for this queue (sending queue) is different from receiving one.

Right now converter config looks like this

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer persistenceListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            @Qualifier("persistenceListenerAdapter") MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter,
                                                            MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(sendQueue());
    listenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```

Probably this setting up only for JSON->Object??

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the default class mapper's headers to convey type information, you need to provide a custom `ClassMapper` or customized `DefaultClassMapper`.

If your type is fixed, the default class mapper falls back to its default type if there is no information in the message to determine the type:

```
myDefaultClassMapper.setDefaultType(MyType.class);
```

Then inject the mapper into the message converter.

Comment: How to do it exactly?? I did

              public classMyTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyType> 

Not too much success

Comment: You need to describe exactly what you want. Do your messages need to be converted always to objects of the same class? Or, do you need to somehow determine which class to convert to, base on some information in the message? If so, what information? With that information, I can help you further.

Comment: I need receive one type and send another type. Types are never gona change. So JSON still the same.

Comment: Use a `DefaultClassMapper`; the default class mapper falls back to its default type if there is no information in the message to determine the type: `myDefaultClassMapper.setDefaultType(MyType.class);`. Then inject the mapper into the message converter.

Comment: This not gonna work. Already tried it. Probably  it works for jakson1 but not for jacson2

Comment: Yes. You're right it works. But only first time on the run. Next listener call broke with this 

2015-09-29 23:09:29.649  WARN 24719 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"sum":486,"days":13}'

But very first message actually has been received WebAppListener: Message Received <Days:2 Sum:320>... so this was decoded! But why it broke on the next call. And also how to setup jakson to send back object?

Comment: There must be junk in the second message if the conversion failed. If you can't figure it out, use a debugger. The exception cause in that log message will have more information. Just send the object back and the converter will take care of the conversion.

Comment: But it always broke like this doesn matter then i run it.

Comment: Yep. Right now I've received the message problem was with Jackson2 bean. But now I have quite opposite problem I cant send data back. My serializer never called.. in debuger I've found that actually Body{} nothing in it. I'll update the question info.